# Typescript angular 5 observable can not get value from input

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am new with typescript. and I don't know why my post variable can't change depend on input.

**home.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="linearsvcParameters.C"/>
<button (click)="TrainModel()" type="button" >TRAIN MODEL
</button>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
public linearsvcParameters: LinearsvcParameter = new LinearsvcParameter(); //this value cant change

public TrainModel(){
this.clfService.TrainModel(this.linearsvcParameters).subscribe((modelAccuracy => {  
  this.modelAccuracy = modelAccuracy;
  console.log(modelAccuracy);
}));
```

}

**ClfService**.service.ts

```
    public TrainModel(linearsvcParameters: LinearsvcParameter): Observable<ModelAccuracy>{        
    console.log('classification.ts' + LinearsvcParameter);
    return this.http.post<ModelAccuracy>(SERVER_URL + 'train', linearsvcParameters);

}
```

**Linearsvc Class**

```
export class LinearsvcParameter{
C: number = 0.1; //default value, i want this value change depend on input home.component.html
```

}

can you help me what miss here?

Comment: So you're saying this.linearsvcParameters isn't updating on button click?

Comment: Just but this in the html (component html) and tell me the result is C changing {{linearsvcParameters.C}}

Comment: yes youre right not updateing on button click @Everett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is solved, and thanks for response. I forgot to add Forms module so I add this module to **app.module.ts**

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is that you are binding to the `C` property in the object `linearsvcParameters`,

```
[(ngModel)]="linearsvcParameters.C"
```

But when the response arrived from the service you are not updating that property but `this.modelAccuracy = modelAccuracy;`

You have to options, binding to the `this.modelAccuracy` property of your `home.component` or update that property inside the subscribe.

```
this.linearsvcParameters.C = modelAccuracy;
```

**Updated**
The other option you have it is change the binding to the property you are updating.

```
[(ngModel)]="modelAccuracy"
```

Let me know how that works!

Comment: my logic is,  i need to update this.modelAccuracy value, thats why this.modelAccuracy = modelAccuracy. if i binding to this.linearsvcParamters.C my value C can be changed as a modelAccuracy value.

Comment: Then, change the binding to that property, I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks @Luillyfe ! you open my mind, my mistake is I forgot to omport Form module, big mistake. the problem is I can not get value of input and pass it to linearsvcParameters.C.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see problem not in TS but in how you're using Observable. You should subscribe to `Observable` in constructor or in `NgOnInit` method.
After that you'll be able to use value that was passed from observable to property.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with making a network call and subscribing to it off of a button click

Comment: my trainmodel method inside this export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {}

Comment: @Everett, I don't think so.

Comment: @user3134652, nice, move subscription to ngOnInit.

Comment: you are right, theres nothing wrong with my code, thanks dude ! @Everett